# How to render axios call correctly in React Native?

Tags: react-native, axios

I have created a component to return the price value when a coin name is passed to the component.

In the console output inside function, it is showing the result but not returning the value.

My code:

MarketPrice.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

function round(num) {
  var m = Number((Math.abs(num) * 100).toPrecision(15));
  return (Math.round(m) / 100) * Math.sign(num);
}

const goForAxios = async (coin) => {
  //setLoading(true);

  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${coin}&tsyms=INR`
  );
  console.log(response.data.INR.toString());
  return response.data.INR.toString();
};

export default function MarketPrice(props) {
  console.log(props.coin);
  const marketPrice = goForAxios(props.coin);
  // return marketPrice;
  console.log("MarketPrice: " + marketPrice);
  return <Text>{round(marketPrice)}</Text>;
}
```

The output in UI is showing as **NaN**
And on console:

```
119.12
ADA
BTC
3058216.2
```

Comment: You need to add state to the component as the price value is only determined upon a successful response to the request. You can look up the useState hook

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the return value of an asynchronous function which won't quite work (as it returns a Promise - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). A better approach would be to add a `result` state which can be conditionally rendered (depending on the value of `props.coin`)

```
export default function MarketPrice(props) {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  const goForAxios = async (coin) => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${coin}&tsyms=INR`
    );
    setResult(response.data.INR);
  };

  const marketPrice = goForAxios(props.coin);
  console.log(result);
  return <div>Market Price: {result ? round(result) : "Not Found"}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it is working now. Also, is there anyway good styling code you suggest for the below SwipeListView items. I want to show in a tabular format with columns on the top and same gap between the values. And coloring to the values based on a condition so that I can show green or red based or loss or profit. The snap. https://ibb.co/b1BGg54